# glsl compiler completely ignore catching the error of missing parentheses after EmitVertex EndPrimitive

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I've recently bumped into an rendering issue that is caused by me inadvertently missed typing the pair of parentheses right after the EmitVertex and EndPrimitive in the OpenGL geometry shader. To my surprise, the glsl compiler didn't throw any compiling error and quietly let it pass.  The end result is an blank screen since no vertex is emitted by the geometry shader.

I'm wondering is it a bug in the compiler or there is any other reason for this.
BTW, I have tested it on nvidia Titan X with Win7 and GTX 750M with Win8. They both have the same problem.

Comment: Post a shader example where this happens.

Comment: No need to post a shader. You can try it on any of your opengl geometry shader by removing the parentheses of EmitVertex() or EndPrimitive().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is definitely a bug if it works the way you described (*e.g.* `EmitVertex );`).

You can always validate your shaders using Khronos' [reference compiler](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/) if you are ever in doubt. That sort of thing is already common in D3D-based software, where shaders are pre-compiled when the software is built; GL does not support hardware-independent pre-compiled shaders, so you would only use this as a validation step rather than part of the compile process.

Even though it will not save runtime, it would not be a bad idea to work that into your software's build procedure so you do not have to wait until your software is actually deployed to catch simple parse errors like this. Otherwise, you will often only learn about these things after a driver version change or the software runs on a GPU it was never tested on before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using glslangValidator as you suggested to verify my problematic geometry shader. It does detect the grammar error:
ERROR: 0:138: 'EmitVertex' : undeclared identifier
I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the nvidia driver. My driver version is 352.86

Comment: Again, after updating nvidia driver to 358.50, released on 10/07/2015. The bug still persists.